# Cannot set the window icon in android

Tags: android, icons, window

How can I set a window icon for all the activities. I have gone through the window features and relative methods to set the features.

Here is the code I have used to set the icon:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.icon);
```

I have called this code in the 'onCreate' method of an activity. Icon is set for the main activity. But whenever I go to other activities, no icon is set in the window. I cannot see any errors in the logcat. Please help me.

Comment: Different icon is working for other activity. But using same icon is not working :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a cache problem :)

I have Uninstalled the application from the emulator and deleted the following files from the 'bin' folder:

- classes.dex
- ApplicationName.apk
- resources.ap_

Deleted the R.java file.
It worked perfectly after reinstalling the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dijo....... you saved my day ......Stackoverflow and android need people like you